# Single word for delightfully frustrated

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, emotions

Is there a word for that feeling when you're waiting in excitement for something to happen, but you're being teased with or denied it? It's a feeling of definite frustration but you're quite happy to sit with it as it's building up  (good) tension and you know satisfaction will be greater as a result of waiting.
Suggestions in other languages, not just English, welcome.

Comment: **Anticipation** would work if you take out the part about being teased/denied.

Answer (score 4):

The word you're looking for may be **tantalized** or **teased**.

OD:

> [**tantalize**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tantalize): Torment or tease (someone) with the sight or
>   promise of something that is unobtainable: *‘such ambitious questions
>   have long tantalized the world's best thinkers’*
>
> [**tease**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tease): Tempt
>   (someone) sexually with no intention of
>   satisfying the desire aroused: *‘she had thrown herself at him and
>   teased him’*
>
> More example sentences:
>
> - ‘Those behind the service claim it will let mobile users ‘flirt,
>     tantalise and tease other mobile users by anonymous text messages’.’
> - ‘With his schoolboy hips and abs to die for, Mick Jagger still
>     cavorts, teases, taunts and leers in exactly the manner you expect him
>     to.’
> - ‘His voice had all of it's previous teasing sexuality gone, only
>     remained the voice of a dangerous man.’
> - ‘Inside the pearly white gates of the heaven in another world,
>     promiscuous women teased men and had many boy friends at the same
>     time.’
> - ‘When she woke up I kissed and teased her.’
> - ‘Sure, Crudup's teasing sexuality during the first act is
>     entertaining, but it's his desperation and her uncertainty that makes
>     the rest of the film so enjoyable.’
> - ‘Again, she kissed him, to tease him into state of fiery desire.’
> - ‘Once, he teased me in class by doing sexual gestures and whatnot.’

Comment: _tantalized_ it is! +1; good to see you in the 10k club!

Comment: @alwayslearning Season's greetings! Thank you. Glad to be in your company.

Comment: I'm wanting to say something along the lines of "You leave me [delightfully frustrated]," or "You have me feeling [that way] once again." As much as I agree with your suggestion of tantalising I'm not sure how I would use it in those contexts...

Comment: @VickyAldridge How about *titillated*? *Titillate*: arouse (someone) to interest or mild excitement, especially through sexually suggestive images or words (OD).